# Pass custom parameters in create action of charges Stripe controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

In the create action of charges controller from Stripe, I would like to get  the command which have just been paid. But I don't know how to pass parameters in the stripe payment form.

This is my actual code :

**charges_controller**

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @command = Command.find(params[:command_id])
    @item = @command.commandable
  end

  def create
    @command = # I would like to have the current command...
    @item = @command.commandable
    # Amount in cents
    amount_in_cents = (@command.total_price * 100).to_i
    customer = StripeTool.create_customer(params[:stripeEmail],
                                          params[:stripeToken])

    charge = StripeTool.create_charge(customer.id,
                                      amount_in_cents,
                                      'Commande Edicouv')

    redirect_to root_path
 end
```

Params when i'm in the create action :

```
Processing by ChargesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
             "authenticity_token"=>"...", 
             "stripeToken"=>"...", 
             "stripeTokenType"=>"card", 
             "stripeEmail"=>"orsay@live.fr"}
```

**views/charges/new**

```
script.stripe-button[src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
data-key="#{Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]}" 
data-description="Règlement de votre achat" 
data-locale="auto" 
data-currency="eur" 
data-panel-label="Payer #{@command.total_price} €" 
data-label="Payer"
data-image="/assets/logo.png" 
data-email="#{current_user.email}" 
data-allow-remember-me="false"]
```

Comment: if i am not wrong  you need to find a parameter in create action which is declared in new action, then you can pass it from hidden field. and agian you can fire find query

Comment: refer this https://launchschool.com/blog/stripe-checkout

Comment: @chaitanya I cannot pass hidden field in stripe form. The params who are passed are the params present in the popup of stripe form, not those on the script charges/new. So I cannot access to it...